# partial Validation for multiple submit button in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

i have one form with dozens of components. currently i am not able to use ajax as its showing some error. i want to validation field only for one submit button but as i have more than one submit button it gives error for others as well. whhen i use immediate for other button action of that button not able to access submitted values.

question is there any way to placed validation for particular submit button when having more than one submit button in a form?

Pls can any one help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  required=”#{!empty param[‘frmName:btnSave’]}” this for the fields with btnSave as id of button on which validation is required.